# How to customize Design of Edititem Template in RadGrid?

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-ajax

I have a RadGrid, when ever i click on edit to edit a row in grid. It shows the below design at edit time.

[image]

But i want it in only  two rows as following:

Row 1: Order Date, Required Date, Company

Row 2: The rest

can we make it in two rows?  I'm looking forward for your answers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.. you can configure your RadGrid to use an Edit table format that you're looking for.

Check this demo on the Telerik demos site for information about using the EditFormSettings ColumnNumber attribute to specify the number of columns you want and how to place items into each of those columns.

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/dataediting/multicolumneditform/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: It relates to creating columns. but i want to divide my fields in rows. Is there any way to show fields in rows instead of columns. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can't design it in rows. There is an example to make it in columns.

Please have a look at [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/dataediting/multicolumneditform/defaultcs.aspx).